# Bad port for 49152-65535/udp

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, firewall, bigbluebutton, ufw, coturn

I am trying to allow ports in firewall for my big blue button coturn server, but when I am running `$ sudo ufw allow 49152-65535/udp`

I am receiving the following error: `ERROR: Bad port`.

Can someone explain to me why it is showing that and how to I solve it? I am in a ubuntu 16.04 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `49152-65535/udp` whereas it should had been `49152:65535/udp`